# How to satisfy the lint rules 'array-callback-return'?

Tags: ecmascript-6, eslint

This is my first cut:

```
const planLimits = {plan1: {condition1: 50, ...}}

function initialisePlanLimits(planLimits) {
  const limits = new Map();
  Object.keys(planLimits).map((planId) => (
    const limitMap = new Map(Object.entries(planLimits[planId]));
    limits.set(planId, limitMap);
  ));
  return limits;
}
```

The linter flags this error: `error  Expected to return a value in this function                                                    array-callback-return`

So I changed to this version:

```
function initialisePlanLimits(planLimits) {
  const limits = new Map();
  Object.keys(planLimits).map((planId) => (
    limits.set(planId, new Map(Object.entries(planLimits[planId])))
  ));
  return limits;
}
```

It throws another error `Unexpected parentheses around single function argument having a body with no curly braces      arrow-parens`

My questions:

1) I reckon I can fix my first version by sticking in a `return null` within the curry bracket. But is there a better, more elegant way? A bogus return statement does not make sense in this context

2) Why the second version fails? Isn't it equivalent to the first version?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I use `forEach` instead of `map`, it will not cause the `array-callback-return` lint error

```
 Object.keys(planLimits).forEach((planId) => (
    const limitMap = new Map(Object.entries(planLimits[planId]));
    limits.set(planId, limitMap);
  ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, accepted answer advocates about using 'forEach,' which is true. Please read below explaination from [ESLint documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/array-callback-return),

> Array has several methods for filtering, mapping, and folding. If we forget to write return statement in a callback of those, it's probably a mistake. If you don't want to use a return or don't need the returned results, consider using .forEach instead.

Answer (score -1):

### TLDR: ESLint and Function Return Values

This issue is caused by not returning a value when using `map()`, see how the `results` are expected according to the docs...

> The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array. (Source: [MDN WebDocs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).)

### Demonstration of Issue in JavaScript

With this code sample of JS, which shows a group of elements...

```
  var newarray = [];
  array.map( (item, index) => {
      newarray.push('<li>' + item + '</li>');
  });
```

I get this error...

```
  Expected to return a value in arrow function  array-callback-return
```

The error goes away if I add a single return to the above function, like so :

```
  var newarray = array.map( (item, index) => {
      return '<li>' + item + '</li>';
  });
```

### `map()` - So why should I use it?

You can clearly see elsewhere, too, on MDN Docs, that what is returned is, *"A new array with each element being the result of the [return value of the] callback function."*  So, if you are using `map()`, it's also a very good idea to also use `return returnvalue`!

*`map()` is a powerful tool.  Don't throw that tool away.*

Comment: The linked thread does not support this answer. It talks about Pascal, where a "function" is distinct from a "procedure". In JavaScript, both are called "functions", whether they return a value or not.

Comment: @Thomas You are right!  Thanks for pointing that out.  I was just in the process of editing this answer, so I omitted that section, and also corrected the `Map()` MDN weblinks to correctly point to `map()` func, and cleaned up my example a bit more.

Comment: perfect answer, i don't know why it has negative score