# Promise.all.then is executed before the individual promises are completed

Tags: javascript

The following sample code represents what am trying to do, and am stumped as to why the `console.log` inside the `Promises.all.then()` is completed before even the individual promises are completed. I am thinking that the `map` statement has something to do with it , may be, but am unsure.

My intention of using a `map` was to collect all successes and or failures and notify the user later on bulk operations.

```js
var requests = []; var success=[]; var failures = [];

requests.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve("foo success"), 2000)));
requests.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => reject("bar failure"), 1000)));
requests.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve("foo2 success"), 2000)));
requests.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => reject("bar2 failure"), 1000)));

Promise.all(requests.map(p => {
    p.then(r => {
        console.log(r)
        success.push(r);
    });
    p.catch((e) => { console.log(e); failures.push(e); });
})).then(function () { console.log("ALL promises completed")})
```

May i know what is wrong with the above code? Am i not implementing the promises as intended.?

Comment: I have an answer to a similar problem, although the problem is stated differently: "How to satisfy the lint rules 'array-callback-return'?": https://stackoverflow.com/a/45418236/2430549

Comment: Here is an additional off-topic comment about code style. `setTimeout` takes any additional arguments and applies them to the callback. You can write this way too, which I think is nicer to look at. `new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000, "foo success"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your `requests.map(...)` callback doesn't *return* anything, so you're mapping the Promises to `undefined` values. Therefore, you're awaiting an array of `undefined` values with the `Promise.all` call. Change to the following:

```
Promise.all(requests.map(p => {
    p.then(r => {
      console.log(r)
      console.log("POSTed a record successfuly");
      success.push(r);
    });
    p.catch((e) => { console.log(e); failures.push(e); });
    return p;
})).then(function () { console.log("POSTED ALL")})
```

**Update**:

As @JoeFrambach pointed out, if you want the `Promise.all` to contain the contents of the original `requests` Promises, you'll want to return the original Promises. Since that's most likely what you want to do, I've updated my answer.

Comment: ahhh, how silly of me, thanks a ton!!! (SO states i can accept this as answer in next 5 minutes)

Comment: This answer actually changes the behavior of the code in your question. Your map can add extra functionality onto each promise, but you should return the original promise, not your augmented promise. `.then` accepts one argument, which is the resolved value of the previous promise. This answer always returns undefined and throws away the response.

Comment: ohh, i see your point, right, i will return the original.. I am using map merely to collect the failures and success and send it as a notification later.. will modify

Comment: Yeah, you can see it by changing the last line to `})).then(function (allResponses) { console.log("POSTED ALL", allResponses)})`
`

Comment: Yep, if your intent is for the result of `Promise.all` to contain the results, you need the original Promises returned. Updated. But keep in mind you may see `"POSTED ALL"` before the success/failure messages.

Answer (score 1):

just return promise from your map callback function

```js
var requests = []; var success=[]; var failures = [];

requests.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve("foo success"), 2000)));
requests.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => reject("bar failure"), 1000)));
requests.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve("foo2 success"), 2000)));
requests.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => reject("bar2 failure"), 1000)));

Promise.all(requests.map(p => {
    p.then(r => {
        console.log(r)
        success.push(r);
    });
    p.catch((e) => { console.log(e); failures.push(e); });
    return p; // ADD THIS LINE
})).then(function () { console.log("ALL promises completed")})
   .catch(function() {console.log("FAILED PROMISE ALL")});
```

Comment: This will kind of work, but keep in mind that `p.then` doesn't "mutate" the Promise, nor does `p.catch`. Therefore, when awaiting the `p` that's returned, you won't be also awaiting the `then` or `catch` callback but the Promise _before_ that. Sometimes that's what you want, but normally you want to return the _new_ promises returned by `.then` and `.catch`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a promise within .map function.
Within .map function make last line as return p.

Promise all expects array of promises. You are returning array of undefined from map function so it immediately gets resolved.